# Typescript how can I return an HTML element multiple times with a loop?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, element

I'm new to Typescript I want to make a function that returns few buttons with the data in the array, I tried to do it by using a for loop like that:

```
    splitLabels(Array: any){
        if (typeof Array != "undefined" && Array != null 
        && Array.length != null && Array.length > 0) {
            
            var labels;
            
            for(let i = 0; i<Array.length; i++){
                labels = <button className='labels'>{Array[i]}</button>;
                
            return labels;
            }       
        }
    }
```

This won't work because it returns only the first index.
So I've looked for some ideas online and I found out that I can use Array.map, but It does not work for me.

```
            Array.map(functions(Array,i){
                return <button className='labels'> {Array} </button>;
            }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't name parameters with the first letter as capital. `Array` is also a 'class' (or function, whatever) and it becomes confusing if you "override it"

Comment: Also, add a more detailed description for "does not work for me". I mean, it is not clear how you are applying `Array.map` to the rest of the code and what does "does not work" mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `for` loop, you have to store your elements in an array, and return it;

```
 splitLabels(Array: any){
        if (typeof Array != "undefined" && Array != null 
        && Array.length != null && Array.length > 0) {
            
            const labels = [];
            
            for(let i = 0; i<Array.length; i++){
                labels.push(<button className='labels'>{Array[i]}</button>)
            } 
            return labels;      
        }
    }
```

**using `Array.map()`:**

```
      return Array.map((text) => (
            <button className='labels'> {text} </button>;
      )
```

Comment: Thanks its working, but what does text refers to?

Comment: The array element, I just made it as "text" to prevent confusion since your array is named as "Array"